# String from SerialPort, convert to byte array then compare with other bytes

Tags: c#, arrays

I can get anything from a single byte up to 7 or 8 bytes coming in from a serial port. Now these bytes are in the form such as 0x06 (ACK) or 0x15 (NAK) to a stream of bytes such as 0x1A, 0x56, 0xF7, 0x01, 0xC3, etc...

Now my code goes more of less like this:

```
    private void mySerialPort_DataReceived (object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        rxString = mySerialPort.ReadExisting();
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
    }

    private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rxString);

        tb_Status.Clear();

        if (bytes = (0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06))
        {
           tb_Status.AppendText("Ok, we are GOOD!!!");
        }
    }
```

But I get the error "Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte[]'""

So when I have an array of bytes (which is coded as a string from the SerialPort), how can I identify just one particular byte in the array and then compare it to another byte?

Thanks

Comment: On which line are you getting the error?

Comment: if (bytes = (0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06))

Comment: 0x... values are converted to int by the compiler by default.

Comment: Thanks, but any idea how I can resolve the issue of comparing each byte in the array?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(bytes.SequenceEquals(new byte[] { (byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x06}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare array to int.

You can iterate through the array's members or use [SequenceEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx):

```
if (bytes.SequenceEqual(new byte[] {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06})
```

Comment: Hey, thanks guys. This works great... My gratitude to the both of you...